# Faster for loop in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, for-loop

Which is faster and why? Is there a noticeable difference?

```
""" my_list=[1,2,3...N] """

for i in my_list:
    do something
```

or

```
for i in range(1,N):
    do something
```

It seems to me that in the second case the range function would be called N times which might be slower but I don't know how the `in` operator really works.

Comment: The `range` function does not get called N times. If you are using Python 3.x the second method is a bit faster and more memory efficient since `range` does not construct the whole list in advance. For Python 2.x you can use `xrange` for the same effect.

Comment: Oh I just meant which is faster in python 3: the first method or the second method?

Comment: @Jérôme In Python 3 the second method is faster. To make it faster and use less memory  in Python 2, you can replace range with xrange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> t = timeit.Timer("""for i in range(3):
...     pass""")
>>> t.timeit(1)
2.199320988438558e-06
```

as apposed to:

```
>>> t = timeit.Timer("""list_a=[0,1,2]
... for i in list_a:
...     pass""")
>>> t.timeit(1)
4.398641522129765e-06
```

You can see the time differences between these operations.
Besides, you should be aware that in python 2 it is more advisable using xrange instead of range if you don't need all these values at the same time (like simple iteration), since it generates a value at each iteration, which could save lots of memory and sometimes even CPU (in more complicated cases).

for more information:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: `print` is not a good choice for performance testing, as I/O operations are heavy and may falsify statistics

Comment: Thank you. What operations would you suggest for good statistical testing?

Comment: You can just use `pass` :)